# Не работает рандомные изображения discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def hug (ctx, member:discord.Member):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        slaa = (random.choice(hug))
        bs = discord.Embed(title = 'Обнимашки')
        bs.add_field(name = ':3', value = f'Пользоватлеь {ctx.message.author} обнял самого себя!')
        bs.set_image(url = slaa)
        await ctx.send (embed = bs)
    if member != ctx.message.author:
        b = discord.Embed (title = 'Обнимашки!')
        b.add_field(name= ':3', value= f'Пользоватлеь {ctx.message.author} обнял {member.mention}')
        b.set_image(url = slaa)
        await ctx.send(embed = b)
```

Есть список из изображений. Переменная slaa рандомно выбирает изображение, но set_image не хочет его добавлять в embed.

Comment: появляется ли какая нибудь ошикба?

Comment: нет, никакой ошибки нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функция и переменная одинаково называется. Замените название переменной hug, например, на hugimage.